# Pure CSS3 (3, 2, 1) Countdown

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a 3 second countdown which automatically starts and then loops. Literally just saying '3' then replaces it with '2' and then finally '1'.

So far the code I'm trying is this:

```
*[class].countdown:before {
    content: '3' !important;
    -webkit-animation:countdowns 3s ease-in-out infinite;
    -moz-animation:countdowns 3s ease-in-out infinite;
    -ms-animation:countdowns 3s ease-in-out infinite;
    -o-animation:countdowns 3s ease-in-out infinite;
    animation:countdowns 3s ease-in-out infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes countdowns {
    33% {content: '3' !important;}
    66% {content: '2' !important;}
    99% {content: '1' !important;}
}
```

Then I simply have this as the HTML:

```
<span class="countdown"></span>
```

However this just displays '3' and nothing more. Anybody got any suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: check this link http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/make-a-stopwatch-using-css3-without-images-or-javascript

Comment: A countdown isn't about styling: it's an information in your page, thus it should be in HTML code and then animated via JS. To inform screen readers about these changes, attribute `aria-live` is quite simple to implement: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Live_Regions) [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ie/dd433065%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `content` property cannot be animated so it gets ignored.

The [@keyframes documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes#Valid_keyframe_lists) states:

> If you include properties that can't be animated in your keyframe rules, they get ignored, but the supported properties will still be animated.

---

You can however do it in another way, if are allowed to use fixed-width fonts.

```
.countdown:before {
    content: '321';

    font-family:monospace;
    display:inline-block;
    width:1ch;
    overflow:hidden;

    animation:countdowns 3s steps(3) infinite;
}

@keyframes countdowns {
    0% {text-indent:0}
    100% {text-indent:-3ch;}
}
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/xtcvc4sw/

Answer (score 0):

The `content` property isn't animate-able via CSS. [Here's a good list](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animated_properties) that covers what is and what isn't animatable.

Comment: I did include the essential parts. "The `content` property isn't animate-able." Not much more to it than that.

Comment: Look at Gaby's answer. It is a lot more detailed and in-depth.

Comment: That's great, and earned him the "top" answer, but still doesn't change the fact that the essential parts of the answer are included in mine.